# The elements such as "Image View" and "Label" are currently displayed at the top instead of the left sidebar in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

[image]

The elements such as "Image View" and "Label" are currently displayed at the top instead of the left sidebar in Xcode as you can see on the image. I tried some things I read on Google but I couldn't find a solution yet. Can you fix?

Comment: Do you mean? - Xcode menu: Editor -> Document Outline

Answer (score 1):

You should click on the document outline icon, shown on the picture in the red circle. Or use the Xcode menu Editor / Document Outline.

[image]